# ActiveRecord: How can I get all of a user's cars without including those that have not been saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a form on `users/show.html.erb` to create a new `car` for that user.

```
<%= form_for(user.cars.build(user_id: @user.id, garage_id: @user.garage.id)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :garage_id, value: @user.garage.id %>

    <%= f.submit "Book It", class: "btn btn-default btn-xs appointment-submit-button" %>
<% end %>
```

After this form on the page, I list all of the user's cars. However, when I loop through the user's cars, it is picking up a newly built, but un-saved car (presumably because of the form above). Is there a way to either a) prevent the car from being built until the form is submitted or b) have the list of cars cycle through only those cars of the user that have already been saved?

I tried putting a function in `user.rb`:

```
def saved_cars
    self.cars.where(!is_new?)
end
```

so that I can loop through this instead, but I can't figure out the syntax. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expound on @marflar's answer, when you look through the user's cars you can check if the car is a `new_record?` and decide to render it.

```
= render @user.cars
```

Then in the partial:

```
<% unless car.new_record? %>
  # render your html here;
<% end %>
```

Alternatively:

```
<% if car.persisted? %>
  # render your html here;
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want ActiveRecord's [new_record?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F) method and its little friend [persisted?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F).